# Sending data back from cloud code

Tags: ios, parse-platform, stripe-payments, parse-cloud-code

I use Stripe in Parse Cloud Code and receive a Stripe ID (String), but I want to send that stripe id back to Xcode. What is the best way of doing this?

I've tried to first of all send the stripe ID to Parse, and in Xcode I do a fetch...
But I think that's a bad idea because if there are multiple users processing the payments at same time, it's hard to get the right stripe ID for the user.

Comment: *"in/to xcode"*??? You mean in/to your app? That is written via Xcode? Show some code, I have no idea what your concern is all about!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[To return data from cloud code, take a look at this tutorial post](https://www.parse.com/docs/cloudcode/guide#cloud-code-cloud-functions).

Basically all you have to do is return the stripe id like this

```
response.success(stripeId);
```

[Receiving data looks like this :](https://www.parse.com/docs/ios/guide#performance-use-cloud-code)

```
[PFCloud callFunctionInBackground:@"averageStars" withParameters:params block:^(NSString *stripeId, NSError *error) {
    if (!error) {
        // code
    }
}];
```